# Do the topology and metric of spacetime determine whether a conformal field theory has a nonzero mass gap?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mathematical-physics, conformal-field-theory, topology, qft-in-curved-spacetime

Many introductions to conformal field theory (CFT) emphasize the case where spacetime is $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the usual flat metric. In those cases, a CFT cannot have a nonzero mass gap, because that would violate scale invariance. But we can also define CFTs on spacetimes $\mathbb{R}\times\Sigma$ where the space part $\Sigma$ is compact, and then a nonzero mass gap is possible. (I think it's actually unavoidable.) Scale invariance isn't an issue in this case, because such a spacetime already has an intrinsic scale even before we define a CFT on it.

What about CFTs on arbitrary $D$-dimensional globally hyperbolic manifolds? Do the topology and metric alone determine whether or not CFTs defined on that spacetime will have a mass gap? I'm especially interested in $D\geq 3$, so an answer that excludes $D\leq 2$ would be fine with me, if that makes things any easier.

The paper [arXiv:1507.00015](https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.00015) studies how the mass gap depends on $\Sigma$, but that paper's goals are both more and less ambitious:

- They're less ambitious in the sense that they consider only static spacetimes with closed $\Sigma$s, and a limited class of CFTs.
- They're more ambitious in the sense that they try to find a quantitative bound on the gap instead of only asking whether it's nonzero. I'm not asking for a quantitative bound here. I'm only asking whether the gap is nonzero. It is nonzero in the cases the paper considers, but I'm asking more generally when it's nonzero.

I'm hoping my question is less ambitious overall. I have a feeling it might even be trivial, but the answer hasn't [dawned on me](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dawn%20on) yet. In particular, my question could be answered (negatively) by citing an example where a single spacetime admits two CFTs, one with a nonzero mass gap and one with no mass gap. Are any such examples known?